# Google Drive API download NODE.JS sample doesn't work

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

Here is my code based on [Google: "Here are examples of performing a file download with our Drive API client libraries." NODE.JS](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads)

```
const fs = require('fs')
const google = require('googleapis')
const googleAuth = require('google-auth-library')

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'] // Full, permissive scope to access all of a user's files, excluding the Application Data folder. Request this scope only when it is strictly necessary.
const TOKEN_DIR = './credentials/'
const TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'token4joeDlEs6.json'
const CLIENT_SECRET_FILEPATH = 'client_secret.json'

var clientSecretStr = fs.readFileSync(CLIENT_SECRET_FILEPATH).toString('utf-8')
var tokenStr = fs.readFileSync(TOKEN_PATH).toString('utf-8')


var credentials = JSON.parse(clientSecretStr) 

var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret
var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id
var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0]
var auth = new googleAuth()
var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl)

oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(tokenStr)

var drive = google.drive('v3');

// ["Examples"-NODE.JS tab](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads)
var fileId = 'OBFUSCATED' // Safeway (OBFUSCATED)
var dest = fs.createWriteStream('out/safeway.txt')
drive.files.get({
  auth: oauth2Client,
  fileId: fileId,
  //alt: 'media'
})
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log('Done');
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('Error during download', err);
    })
    .pipe(dest);
```

## RUNS WITHOUT ERRORS:

```
$ node joeDlSample.js
Done
$
```

## EXPECTED RESULT

out/safeway.txt to contain my shopping list. :)

## ACTUAL RESULT

out/safeway.txt contains

```
{
  "access_token" : "OBFUSCATED.OBFUSCATED",
  "expires_in" : 3600,
  "token_type" : "Bearer"
}
```

## 2nd RUN CLOSER TO EXAMPLE

I also uploaded a .jpg picture, & uncommented the `alt: media` line in the code

## EXPECTED RESULT

out/elb.jpg to contain elb picture

## ACTUAL RESULT

out/elb.jpg contains

```
{
  "access_token" : "OBFUSCATED.OBFUSCATED",
  "expires_in" : 3600,
  "token_type" : "Bearer"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the right fileID, seems to work for me and also for @noogui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get Downloading Files in Drive API working by combining the [Drive NodeJS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs) and the [Download Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) sample for NodeJS.

From the NodeJS Quickstart there's this line:

```
authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
```

I created my own `downloadFile` function to download files instead of listing files and modified the above mentioned line to

```
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), downloadFile);
```

And here's the `downloadFile` function part from the NodeJS sample:

```
function downloadFile(auth){
  var service = google.drive('v3');
  var fileId = 'FILE_ID_OF_SHOPPINGLIST_TEXT_FILE';
  var dest = fs.createWriteStream('/usr/local/google/home/username/Downloads/shoppinglist.txt');

  service.files.get({
      auth: auth,
      fileId: fileId,
      alt: 'media'
  })
      .on('end', function () {
        console.log('Done');
      })
      .on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Error during download', err);
      })
      .pipe(dest);
}
```

The downloaded file in my Downloads folder:

[image]

Works for me :)

Comment: Great, works for me too. Sad that there is no documentation or even example for DFA reporting but this solution worked like charm :)

Comment: @Actung glad you found it useful. What's DFA reporing BTW?

Comment: DFA is DoubleClick for Advertisers or DoubleClick Campaign Manager for online Advertising

Comment: Hi everyone. The problem seems to have been a "cold" access token. I made it work using a recent one.
Thanks,
Love and peace,
Joe